# Verify Oauth2 authorization token to see if issued for specific client

Tags: oauth-2.0

How can I verify that the provided authorization code is issued for my specific client app (maybe using its client id or even client secret)?

I need this because I will have multiple OAuth2 client apps and the authorization codes will be delivered to the app asynchronously. As these values are tied to each other in some way I don't know, maybe we can verify this? Like asymmetric encryption's public key signing.

Please note that the authorizing server doesn't support passing extra data to get it later alongside the authorization code.

Answer (score 1):

The authorization code is bound to the client it was issued.

This is strictly enforced by the RFC6749 and stated in [4.1.3. Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) section.

The specification has following stated,

> The authorization server MUST:
>
> - Ensure that the authorization code was issued to the authenticated confidential client, or if the client is public, ensure that the code
>   was issued to "client_id" in the request

I guess you don't have to explicitly verify the code. Instead, you can use the code to generate the token. If the intended client is requesting the token, then it would return the token. Otherwise, the request will be denied.

Comment: "I guess you don't have to explicitly verify the code", yes I have. because my app handles authentication with different clients created for different servers. Servers send the authorization code to my app using the redirection uris. The question is how can I verify that which client initiated the auth flow resulting in this code to be delivered to the app. For now, I'm using an extra query parameter so server sends back it to the app and I can choose the intended client.

Comment: Okay so if you want to verify the client before making a token call, then I don't think OAuth2 has any native support for this. I guess you have to go with the custom parameter. There's something called the 'state' parameter in oauth2 but the purpose of it is quite different from what you're trying to achieve here. Whatever you send in the state parameter of your authorization request, you'd get the same along with your authorization_code in the redirect uris. But it's mainly used to prevent CSRF attacks.

Comment: As the oauth2 is just a specification rather than a implementation, i think there's a way to verify what i want. like asymmetric encryption. i will wait until someone can provide an answer directly for this. thanks.